# There's a box supposed to pop up after clicking the "Click Me" button

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on variables and loop frames and stumbled across this problem. I tried switching some things around but none have succeeded. I put the code in a validator and it showed the document as valid.

Whats missing?

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>JavaScript Example</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function substitute() {
      var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value
  
   if (myValue.length == 0) {
   alert('Please enter a real value in the text box!');
   return;
   }
   var myTitle = document.getElementById('title');
   myTitle.innerHTML = myValue;
  }
 </script>
 
</head>
<body>
 <h1 id="title">JavaScript Example</h1>
 
 <input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
 <input type="submit" value="Click Me" onclick="substitute" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The page being formally valid doesn't mean the code inside is correct.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally missed semicolon in the end of `myValue` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the name of a variable holding a function doesn't call the function. You have to actually call it explicitly.

This is usually done by placing `()` after the reference to the function.

```
onclick="substitute()"
```

Comment: Does this mean a value goes in the () ?

Comment: @Tech_Ninja — They are called "Arguments" not values. And no. Hence why I didn't put one there in my example.

Comment: Could you please restate in different words what needs to be changed.